# How to return the values that do not appear in both columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to learn some SQL and I have these two tables and i would like to make a query that selects the titles that have no reviews.Can you please help me?

[image: Movies]

[image: Rating]

This is what i thought i should be, but it seems pretty far from it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT title    
FROM Movie, Rating    
WHERE Movie.mID != Rating.mID;
```

Comment: `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN . . . WHERE`.  There are many different ways.  What have you tried?

Comment: Can you provide more information such as your SQL query?

Comment: Sure, but it's not much

Comment: used code formatting block for sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT title
 FROM movie m
 WHERE m.mid NOT IN (SELECT mid
                       FROM rating)
```